# Setting toolbar items for a navigationController

Tags: iphone

I am trying to set items for a navigationController using the following call

```
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: shareButton, nil];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
```

This adds nothing to the toolbar.

I can hide and show the toolbar using

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

But cant make the items appear.

How does one set the items. ?

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

toolbar is a read-only property.  You set toolbars in this way:

> toolbar The custom toolbar associated
>   with the navigation controller.
>   (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic,readonly)
>   UIToolbar *toolbar Discussion This
>   property contains a reference to the
>   built-in toolbar managed by the
>   navigation controller. Access to this
>   toolbar is provided solely for clients
>   that want to present an action sheet
>   from the toolbar. You should not
>   modify the UIToolbar object directly.
>
> Management of this toolbar’s contents
>   is done through the custom view
>   controllers associated with this
>   navigation controller. For each view
>   controller on the navigation stack,
>   you can assign a custom set of toolbar
>   items using the
>   setToolbarItems:animated: method of
>   UIViewController.

Edit: so you should do this:

```
[self setToolbarItems:items animated:NO];
```

Edit: here's how to add a right bar button item:

```
- (void) addRightButton
{
    UIButton *rightBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [rightBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mybutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    rightBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40 );
    [rightBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightBtn];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarBtn;
}
```

Edit: to create flexible/fixed space items programmatically, use this:

```
- (id)initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItem)systemItem target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

values settable for systemItem include  UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace and   UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace.   Check the documentation for the UIBarButtonItem class:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Edit: the question was clarified.   The toolbar along the bottom has nothing to do with the navigationItem or the navigation controller, it's just a UIToolbar.   You need to either set it up entirely in IB or set up an outlet in your class and set it up / finalize it in code.

Comment: So what should I do? How is a custom toolbar added in the code?

Comment: Note the last sentence: use the setToolbarItems:animated: method of the UIViewController class (which your UIViewController subclass inherits for free).  edit: just added the code for you in an edit to my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I want space between the items? I have two buttons, I would like one on the left, one on the right.

Comment: set the leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem properties of the self.navigationItem directly, that's what I do

Comment: That sets the top navigation bar button position, but not the toolbar which has its items added using an array of buttons.

Comment: If you can make  a complete statement of what you want, then perhaps we can address it.

Comment: How can one add a UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace to the array of items. How is one of these fixedSpace items created and its size set? Is it possible in the code or does it have to be in IB?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?  If you start with your higher rather than lower level goals, then there may be a more appropriate route to take.

Comment: All I would like is a toolbar at the bottom. with the trash icon at the right hand side. please check updated question.

Comment: You've completely changed the question, but at least we're getting closer to what you want at last.    That toolbar long the bottom has nothing to do with the navigation item, it's just a UIToolBar.  You could create it and initialize it all in IB, or in code.

Comment: Well, this [self setToolbarItems:items animated:NO]; actually set those buttons at the botton and their triggers work. I just need spacing now.

Comment: I already added an edit referring you to how to create a fixed or flexible space item in code

Comment: @Helium3 back two comments ago.   Ah my mistake, the toolbar along the bottom is not "just a UIToolbar", it is indeed associated with the navigation controller, you're right about that.   Glad to be of assistance.